# Parameter passing to the functions to be executed before and after main()

Tags: c, linux

`__attribute__ ((<attibute>))` can be used to execute the functions before and after `main()` like `constructor` (as setup function) and `destructor` (as cleanup function). To my surprise, even these two compile and run fine, if parameters are also passed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myStartupFunction (int a, int b) __attribute__ ((constructor));
void myDestructorFunction (int a, int b) __attribute__ ((destructor));


void myStartupFunction (int a, int b)
{
    printf("Before main\n");
}

void myDestructorFunction (int a, int b)
{
    printf("After main\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("Inside main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But since I have no control (maybe I am wrong) over the invocation and execution of these two functions, why such facility is provided. I mean who will pass parameters to these functions if such a definition is made? And if OS calls these two functions, what parameters it decides to pass and how?

Comment: Here's how I would figure it out:  Set up this scenario (you already have the code), Set breakpoints on the two functions, and observe the callstack as shown in your Debugger.  It should tell you what component called your functions, and with what parameters.

Comment: Someone [already asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974553/arguments-to-attribute-constructor-style-functions), but got no answer until now. I'm curious too as the GCC documentation doesn't say much about it.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour as-of the C and the POSIX-standard. Entry point for a program is `main` and anything else is beyond any guarantees by the standard. There are safer ways to accomplish whatever you want. gcc does not guarantee you can use standard library functions without these extensions (well, it can't because it does not provide these libraries, not typically the startup code).

Comment: @jweyrich: gcc does not provide the crt, nor the library, so it cannot make guarantees when these functions are called. That's one reason I don't use them in one of my projects.

Comment: @Olaf: your comments assure a valid answer I guess. I'd upvote :-)

Comment: @jweyrich: Well, I give it a try. Just got too much DV without comment the last time for such hard-to-prove answers. Let's see. (If you find any typos, feel free to correct them; I had a long discussion about a similar subject already).

Comment: They are probably called as if they were casted to `void()`. This invokes undefined behavior but on most platforms the functions will work but either have garbage values for the parameters or will crash on reading them.

Comment: @Dani: What is `void()`?

Comment: Re the paramters. "running fine" is a broad term, as you don't even access these parameters. I suspect they are unspecified, thus any access is UB.

Comment: @Olaf: function with no parameters that returns nothing

Comment: @Dani: That would be `void (void)`. `void()` is a K&R-style function type with unspecified function arguments.

Comment: you should learn about the `atexit()` function.  the `_attribute_` is a gcc extension (not portable)  so should be avoided.  Strongly suggest, do not try to turn `C` into `C++`

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behaviour as-of the C and the POSIX-standard (which bases on the C standard for this). Starting point for program execution is `main`, [5.1.2.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1).  Anything else is beyond any guarantees by the standard.

The `__attribute__` syntax is not part of Linux, nor even related to it. It is a gcc (and possibly others like clang) extension which partially provides C++ initialisers for static variables.

However, gcc does not guarantee you can use standard library functions within these extensions. Actually, it cannot, because it does not control the application startup code, nor the system library.

This startup code/run-time environment (aka C run-time, "crt") is responsible to setup static variables, initialise the standard library (e.g. memory management for `malloc` & friends), etc. It also calls these "constructors".

So, you have to get a guarantee from the run-time environment and the libraries If you want to use such constructs. In general, there are other, safer/standard ways to accomplish whatever you want. E.g. call them in `main` explicitly or generate the calls automatically. That way you also have full control over what arguments you pass and how.

Note: `__attribute__` in general is not even related to "running functions". It is just to add additional constraints/features to a function (or types, variables, etc.) or tell the compiler about special usage. It is just the `"constructor"` and `"destructor"` attributes which are related to the behaviour you ask for.

The [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) does not mandate a specific signature for the functions. Presumably this is left to the run-time. You might want to check your target environment.

Comment: Agreed. The language specifications (C99 and C11) have absolutely no knowledge of function attributes. Good point about entry points. +1